# need to read a specific response header after sending "POST" information for login

Tags: php, php-curl, response-headers

I have trouble reading the value of a specific response header. I'm posting login information and when ok, there is a token set in the response headers. 
I'm able to list all the headers, but how do I read the value of that one specific header?

I searched and found the code which list all headers nicely howerver, those are lines / strings with name of header and the value. Still can't figure out how to read that one value.

```
$ch = curl_init('http://url');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: 
application/json','Content-Type: application/json')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
list($headers, $content) = explode("\r\n\r\n",$response,2);

// Print header
foreach (explode("\r\n",$headers) as $hdr)
    printf('<p>Header: %s</p>', $hdr);
```

there is a line "Header: x-token: xxxxxxx" as output
I now need the xxxxxx to go into a variable...

Comment: Maybe your header is in json format? Try json_decode($response);

Comment: No, the output from CURL in raw is just one string with all the headers, the list and explode and the foreach is printing parts of the string (headers) on a separate line